# UITableView: Can detect cell selection via tap gesture but not didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a UITableView embedded in a [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover). I can see the whole view and select cells except for the one at the bottom. Pressing the bottom row does not cause didSelectRowAtIndexPath to be invoked. I tried adding a UITapGestureRecognizer to the view to intercept touches and computing the corresponding cell with the code below and found that it works. I am trying to understand why didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not being called even though the table view is receiving touch events.

```
CGPoint touchLocation = [sender locationInView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *tappedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchLocation];
NSInteger row = [tappedIndexPath row];
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect WEPopver will add a transparent view to catch all touches and dismiss on touch outside. Did you add gesture recognizer on the table view (not it's parent)? Also, isn't WEPopover dismissed when you tap on the visible part of table view?

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the UITapGestureRecognizer, you don't need it. My guess is that either

1) Your WEPopover is smaller than your UITableView. Set the clipsToBounds property on the WEPopover to YES and see if you still have this issue. You can also double check the height of your UITableView frame and WEPopover frame and make sure they are the same.

2) You have some sort of transparent view covering the bottom cell. Check your view hierarchy and set the color of transparent views to something like [UIColor redColor] and make sure you don't have something on top of your UITableView.

Can you touch on the bottom cell and scroll?

Comment: The gesture recognizer was a test to determine whether the viewable part of the table view responded to touches. Niether of your two conditions hold in this case. No, touch to scroll doesn't work for the bottom. It's like the tableview is getting touches for that part (gesture recognizer) but not translating them into UITableView events.